# using loop_var on item from parent task, avoid or control over looping in child task for values only pertaining to parent item

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

Team,

I have a parent task that runs child IncludeTask and from this I have a value `item.item.0.device`

Now, in child IncludeTask, I have to use this `item.item.0.device` just in replacement of one value and rest of the values in loop are to be from inventory values below for just that parent item device and not ALL devices in values. however, issues is child loop is looping on all devices instead of just the device that got qualified from parent task. like it is also honoring /dev/sda after entering block that is only for nvme device type.

values:

```
local_volume_mount_disks:
  - device: /dev/sdf
    partitions:
      - number: 1
        start: 0%
        end: 25%
        storage_class:  test

  - device: /dev/nvme2n1
    partitions:
      - number: 1
        start: 0%
        end: 100%
        storage_class:  test
```

parent task that sets value for `item.item.0.device`

```
- name: "Run Tasks from file on condition device is not root"
  include_tasks:
    file: pfm_inventory_device_cp.yml
    apply:
      tags: pfm_inventory_device_cp
  loop: "{{ is_device_root.results | unique }}"
  when:
    - item.rc == 1
```

child task

```
    - name: Create ext4 filesystem on partitions for NVME type device
      filesystem:
        fstype: ext4
        dev: "{{ loop_var_nvme.0.device }}{{ nvme_extn }}{{ loop_var_nvme.1.number }}"
      loop:  "{{ local_volume_mount_disks|subelements('partitions') }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: loop_var_nvme
      when: item.item.0.device is regex("nvme\w+")
```

Now, what is happening is my child task instead of skipping sda* device it is getting executed on non-match regex because of loop that am using inside.

error output

```
 TASK [local_volume_mount : Create ext4 filesystem on partitions for NVME type device] ***
 Friday 07 May 2021  16:48:48 +0000 (0:00:00.063)       0:00:11.060 ************ 
   ok: [node1] => (item=[{'device': '/dev/nvme2n1', 'partitions': [{'number': 1, 'start': '0%', 'end': '100%', 'storage_class': 'test'}]}, {'number': 1, 'start': '0%', 'end': '100%', 'storage_class': 'test'}])

   failed: [node1] (item=[{'device': '/dev/sdf', 'partitions': [{'number': 1, 'start': '0%', 'end': '25%', 'storage_class': 'test'}, {'number': 2, 'start': ‘0%’, 'end': ’25%’, 'storage_class': 'test'}]}, {'number': 1, 'start': '0%', 'end': '25%', 'storage_class': 'test'}]) => {"ansible_loop_var": "loop_var_nvme", "changed": false, "loop_var_nvme": [{"device": "/dev/sdf", "partitions": [{"end": "25%", "number": 1, "start": "0%", "storage_class": "test"}, {"end": "50%", "number": 2, "start": "25%", "storage_class": "test"}]}, {"end": "25%", "number": 1, "start": "0%", "storage_class": "test"}], "msg": "Device /dev/sdfp1 not found."}
```

expected out

```
 TASK [local_volume_mount : Create ext4 filesystem on partitions for NVME type device] ***
 Friday 07 May 2021  16:48:48 +0000 (0:00:00.063)       0:00:11.060 ************ 
   ok: [node1] => (item=[{'device': '/dev/nvme2n1', 'partitions': [{'number': 1, 'start': '0%', 'end': '100%', 'storage_class': 'test'}]}, {'number': 1, 'start': '0%', 'end': '100%', 'storage_class': 'test'}])

   skipping: [node1] => (item=[{'device': '/dev/sda', 'partitions': [{'number': 1, 'start': '0%', 'end': '25%', 'storage_class': 'test'}]}, {'number': 1, 'start': '0%', 'end': '100%', 'storage_class': 'test'}])
```

Comment: not sure how more clarity is needed. please explain what is not clear I have put up everything.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be in the use of `loop_var` to get the value of list elements, but using `item` in the `when` condition. Either use `item` everywhere, or `loop_var_nvme`.

A task like this, skips the item when device does not match "nvme":

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "Device = {{ loop_var_nvme.0.device }}; Device number = {{ loop_var_nvme.1.number }}"
  loop: "{{ local_volume_mount_disks|subelements('partitions') }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: loop_var_nvme
  when: loop_var_nvme.0.device is regex("nvme\w+")
```

When run:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=[{'device': '/dev/sdf', 'partitions': [{'number': 1, 'start': '0%', 'end': '25%', 'storage_class': 'test'}]}, {'number': 1, 'start': '0%', 'end': '25%', 'storage_class': 'test'}])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'device': '/dev/nvme2n1', 'partitions': [{'number': 1, 'start': '0%', 'end': '100%', 'storage_class': 'test'}]}, {'number': 1, 'start': '0%', 'end': '100%', 'storage_class': 'test'}]) => {
    "msg": "Device = /dev/nvme2n1; Device number = 1"
}
```